# might find or might have found

Tags: grammaticality

Under which grammatical rule does this fall?
Which is grammatically correct:

> (1) A teacher **might find** it difficult to explain a lecture in the past.

or

> (2) A teacher **might have found** it difficult to explain a lecture in the past.

Comment: They are both correct; it depends on what you are trying to say.

Comment: Both are grammatically correct. When is the teacher speaking?

Comment: I am trying to describe a situation that might or might not have happened in the distant past (no exact time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Have* + past participle of the verb is in **present perfect tense**. The first sentence is in **present tense**. Both are grammatically correct.

Comment: I am trying to describe a situation that might or might not have happened in the distant past (no exact time) so I think the second sentence "might have found" is the correct one to my situation?

Comment: Yes, I agree with that.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to fall under the rules of conditional tense.

"A teacher might find it difficult to explain a lecture in the past" means a teacher might have difficulties explaining, to a class now, a lecture that was delivered in the past.

"A teacher might have found it difficult to explain a lecture in the past" means that in the past a teacher might have difficulty explaining a lecture - ie she would deliver the lecture without additional explication.

The past conditional in the second example - "might have found" - indicates that the difficulty is in the past, implying that the difficulty occurred at the same time as the lecture was delivered. On the other hand, the present conditional in the first - "might find" - indicates that the difficulty occurs now, as opposed to the lecture, which was delivered in the past.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, unfortunately I can't up vote your answer (I am still new and I have a low reputation) and I can't choose two answers to a single question.

Answer (score 0):

The first, *A teacher might find it difficult to explain a lecture in the past*, is ambiguous between

> A teacher might at some time in the future find it difficult to explain a lecture which happened in the past.

and

> It might be that, at some time in the past, a teacher found it difficult to explain a lecture.

The second reading is not very likely, but it is possible (particularly bearing in mind that historically *might* was the past of *may*, and it does still sometimes turn up used in that way in literary writing).

Your second, *A teacher might have found it difficult to explain a lecture in the past*, is unambiguous.